# Checking if a message is a DM. (Discord.js and discord.js-commando)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How can I check if a message is a DM in Discord.js? I have tried several ways on how to test against this, I have tried these methods:

```
if (msg.channel.isDM) ... Produced undefined
if (msg.isDM) ... Produced undefined
if (msg.channel.DMChannel.isDM) ... produced undefined
if (msg.DMChannel) ... produced undefined
if (msg.channel.DMChannel.dm) ... produced undefined
if (msg.channel.dm) ... produced undefined
```

I have tried everything after producing `msg` in a console, and trying to decipher where the heck I do this at. Even the documentation isn't very clear on WHERE to check for this at. I have looked at multiple "solutions" who just spout `<message>.channel.dm`. Well... that doesn't work.

EDIT:
So it does seem it is `<message>.isDM`. However, in my commands this does not work. I can find `isDM` in the array and when I `console.log(msg)` it produced `true` which is expected. However, doing `console.log(msg.isDM)` is printing out `undefined`. It seems weird because it obviously is defined.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found a couple ways to handle this:

`<message>.channel.type === 'dm'` However this only includes the single DM, but will allow group, etc.

`message.guild === null` will check for all DMs (if the messages server is null that will return true if the message was not sent via a server, that then must be a dm.)

Answer (score 7):

`DMChannel` is a class, so `message.channel instanceof DMChannel` should work.

Comment: epic and simple and uses vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on("message", msg =>  { 
    
   if(msg.guild==null &&msg.author.id!=='botDiscordId'){
    msg.reply('dosomethinghere')
   }
});
```

This uses the guild class and will reply to the users message you can tale the msg.reply and change it to whatever, I would recommend putting the botDiscordId in the field so the bot doesn't recognize it's own messages.