# Bot does not detect messages on DMs (AI) || Discord.JS V.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: client.config.openai,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith("!")) return;
  if (message.channel.type !== ChannelType.DM) return;

  let conversationLog = [
    { role: "system", content: "Hello, how can I help you?" },
  ];

  conversationLog.push({
    role: "user",
    content: message.content,
  });

  await message.channel.sendTyping();

  const result = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: conversationLog,
  });

  message.reply(result.data.choices[0].message);
});
```

This is my problem, I try to create a chatbot that will respond to DMs-only and not to any other channel/guild but it fails! When I turn `ChannelType.DM` to `ChannelType.GuildText` and chat on a Text Channel it responds! What should I do? And by the way, these are my intents:

```js
const {
  Guilds,
  GuildMembers,
  GuildMessages,
  MessageContent,
  DirectMessages,
  GuildVoiceStates,
} = GatewayIntentBits;
```

And these are my Partials:

```js
const { User, Message, GuildMember, ThreadMember } = Partials;
```

Any answer is accepted!

### NOTE:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729041/checking-if-a-message-is-a-dm-discord-js-and-discord-js-commando#:%7E:text=client.on%20%28%22message%22%2C%20msg%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20if%20%28msg.guild%3D%3Dnull%20%26%26msg.author.id%21%3D%3D%27botDiscordId%27%29,so%20the%20bot%20doesn%27t%20recognize%20it%27s%20own%20messages.) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204626/how-do-i-reply-to-a-message-only-if-it-was-from-a-dm-in-discord-js-v14) answer doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Do you have any partials enabled?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Here's my partials: `const { User, Message, GuildMember, ThreadMember } = Partials;`

Comment: Thanks, I've just posted an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DM channels can be uncached, so you'll also need to add the `Channel` partials:

```js
const { GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    // ...
  ],
  partials: [Partials.Channel, Partials.Message],
});
```